# How to get query string in controller from a GET request minus one param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

My Rails app receives a GET request with the following params

```
https://example.com/auth?code=ABCD&hmac=EFGH&host=IJKL
```

I need to get the query string without the `hmac` param so it looks like this `code=ABCD&host=IJKL`

Can someone help me get started?

Comment: `params.except(:hmac)`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't feel very elegant but I got it to work with this

```
params.except(:hmac, :controller, :action).to_unsafe_hash.to_query
```

or

```
Rack::Utils.build_query(request.query_parameters.except("hmac"))
```

Hopefully someone has a cleaner solution